# Should I use Generic Type or Wildcard when trying to get a list of objects?

Tags: java, sql, spring, generics

I'm trying to get a list of generic objects. Those Objects are Entities, so the lists are like `List<Employee>`, `List<Recruit>` and so on.

I have many Entities from `PostgreSQL` tables and want to simply get a list based on the type entered. I'm trying to use Wildcard but it says

> Consider defining a bean of type java.lang.Class in your configuration.

My function in `GenericDaoImpl`:

```
public List<?> findFromTable(String tableName) {
    return getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT * from " + tableName).getResultList();
}
```

Comment: Given that this could return objects of different types, all you can safely return there is `List<?>`.

Comment: Also, https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Named parameters are suggested in JPQL https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the Type as well in your function to make more sense. superType is the root class of your entities. If you have model your classes and have a coomon parent  :

```
public  <T extends superType> List<T> findFromTable(String tableName, Class<T> clz) {
    return getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT * from " + tableName).getResultList();
}
```

If you don't have common parent then you'll use wild card.

```
public List<?> findFromTable(String tableName)
```

Comment: I don't have a common parent. Now I tried to start it and it shows Description:

A component required a bean of type 'net.lacit.militaryRegistr.dao.GenericDao' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'net.example.Registr.dao.GenericDao' in your configuration.